# Getting 'the type or namespace name' trying to DllImport in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, dllimport

Error

> Assets/Scripts/osx.cs(4,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CoreGraphics' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

My code:

```
[DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics")]
static extern CoreGraphics.CGSize CGDisplayScreenSize (uint display);
```

How to I access external libs from Unity3d? Specifically `CoreGraphics` for `CGDisplayScreenSize`.

Comment: The error is not from the DllImport attribute but from `CoreGraphics.CGSize`. Where are you defining `CoreGraphics` at? as I'm assuming you are not using Xamarin

Comment: No, this is in Unity. I guess I'm not, its just a struct with 2 floats. I figured DllImport would import it. So I have define it first?

Comment: Yes you do, `DllImport` defines the entry point, marshaling, etc.. but it is not going to import & transform types into C# equivalates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the ObjC return type, `CoreGraphics.CGSize` in terms a C# type and you will be fine.

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyCGSize
{
    public nfloat width;
    public nfloat height;
}

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics")]
static extern MyCGSize CGDisplayScreenSize(uint display);
```